# How to Style Elements in AWeber Form w/External CSS: Treat Two Identical Elements Differently?

Tags: javascript, html, css, aweber

I'm using a javascript-created AWeber form in a lightbox on my site. Because it's a lightbox, I'm only allowed to use javascript - the raw HTML for the form isn't available.

In the form, I've got two separate lines of text, and I want each of them to be a different color. The problem is that each line of text is enclosed in a  element, and I can't figure out how to code differently for each  via external CSS, which (as far as I can tell) is my only option for styling the text in this situation.

I'm thinking that there must be a workaround for this, but I don't know what that might be. Here's the page, if anyone wants to take a look:

http://radionowheremusic.com/mobiletest.html

Click on the text that says "Subscribe to my Email Newsletter." to launch the lightbox; I'd like the "Downloading Music From" text to be orange, and the "Radio Nowhere" text to remain gray.

Thanks!

Comment: The first text is within a `strong` element, whereas the second is not – so easy to target using the element selector.

Comment: That's the ticket. Thanks so much, I was hoping it was something that simple, but didn't realize you could target <strong>.